# Why can I not access my javascript constructors function from outside

Tags: javascript

This way I create my object:

```
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel("other");
```

Why can I not call `myViewModel.setHasOne(value)` from outside the viewmodel?

I get always this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHasOne' of undefined

I know I can set the properties directly, but I would like to know how can I do it with a method?

Here's my function:

```
function MyViewModel(other) {

    var self = this;    
    self.other = other; 
    self.hasOne = false;

    this.setHasOne= function (value) {
        self.hasOne = value;
    };          

    return this;        
}
```

Comment: Constructors should not use `return`, and if they use, it must not return a value. Just remove the `return` from the function.

Comment: Judging by the error, looks like you are trying to call `setHasReplies` and not `setHasOne`

Comment: @Teemu `return this` is equivalent to `return` inside a constructor.

Comment: go-oleg corrected the error!

Comment: @RobW Well... that's something I've read from books, but seems it was over a decade a go... ; ). If you're right with this, it means, that the erranous part of the OP's code is not in the post.

Comment: Where are your snippets located relative to eachother?  This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYVt4/) works fine with no errors.

Comment: The error means that `myViewModel` is `undefined`, which implies that `new MyViewModel("other")` returns `undefined` which is literally impossible.

Comment: @FelixKling Unless there occurs an error in the constructor function before `return this;`. HelloWorld, have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @Teemu: Right, if the script somehow terminates before the value is assigned and the variable is accessed later somehow then it could be indeed `undefined`. But `new MyViewModel("other")` would not return `undefined` in any case ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Actually it can, please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6djXG/). At the moment we don't know when exactly OP is calling the method. Maybe it happens in an event handler, or just out of the scope...

Comment: @Teemu: You are generating an error, and that's ok. But as result the whole script will terminate. The expression `new MyViewModel("other")` is not completely evaluated and the assignment won't take place. `myViewModel` is `undefined` because it was never assigned a value, not because `new ...` *returns* `undefined`. See http://jsfiddle.net/6djXG/1/. `new ....` will *always* return an object.

Comment: @FelixKling That's true, but the snippet shows that `myViewModel` can be `undefined` under some circumstances. However, we have to wait OP's response to all questions here in comments to find a solution, since there's also this weird: `"Why can I not call ... outside the viewmodel?`". The call is outside the scope?

Comment: You mentioned you couldn't call myViewModel.setHasOne(value) from outside the viewmodel. what scope you referring by saying viewModel. can you explain a little bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't have any problem and it should work, maybe you have a typo somewhere. But based on the error, the problem is not with defining the method but with the instance of your class, the error says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHasOne' of undefined
```

Which means that for whatever reason your variable "myViewModel" is undefined, thus it cannot find "setHasOne" for an undefined value.

Regarding your code, defining the methods inside the constructor called "Privileged Methods". The only benefit of this kind of methods is that they have access to private variables which are defined inside the constructor. If you are not using this feature it'd be better to define your method as a "Public Method". The reason is, the public methods use a share memory space for every instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function MyViewModel(other) {

var self = this;    
this.other = other; 
this.hasOne = false;

}
MyViewModel.prototype.setHasOne = function(value) {
  this.hasOne = value;
};
```

note: you don't need the `return` statement in the constructor because you already have access to `this`.

Comment: I know that return this is done implicitly. I just do it explicity, there is no harm in doing it just obvious programming...